# How to implement distributed tracing with spring boot 1.5?

Tags: spring-boot, jaeger

I want to implement tracing using Uber Jaegar with the spring boot 1.5 version.
I did basic R&D with dependency  but not working

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
    <artifactId>opentracing-spring-jaeger-cloud-starter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And I have added following properties.

```
#Jaeger Configuration
opentracing.jaeger.udp-sender.host=localhost
opentracing.jaeger.udp-sender.port=6831
opentracing.jaeger.const-sampler.decision=true
opentracing.jaeger.enabled=true
opentracing.jaeger.log-spans=true
opentracing.jaeger.service-name=ms-name
```

I am getting the following error.

```
Parameter 2 of method reporter in io.opentracing.contrib.java.spring.jaeger.starter.JaegerAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'io.opentracing.contrib.java.spring.jaeger.starter.ReporterAppender' that could not be found.
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: @Elikill58, I am getting Following error.
Parameter 2 of method reporter in io.opentracing.contrib.java.spring.jaeger.starter.JaegerAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'io.opentracing.contrib.java.spring.jaeger.starter.ReporterAppender' that could not be found.

Comment: @Elikill58 have updated full details.